cPanel - Python App, passenger_wsgi app is not found
When I just created a fresh python 3.11 app in cPanel it logs following error:
/home/sulphur1/virtualenv/basic/3.10/bin/python3.10_bin: Error while finding module specification for '/home/sulphur1/basic/passenger_wsgi.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/sulphur1/basic/passenger_wsgi'). Try using '/home/sulphur1/basic/passenger_wsgi' instead of '/home/sulphur1/basic/passenger_wsgi.py' as the module name.

But in python2 it runs fine, but isn't compatible with my django project.
Secondly, when I try to bash python -m passwenger_wsgi it runs successfully.
Can anyone solve this error? Why's this happening?
I tried different versions of python3 but none were successfull.
Basic successfull python app would lauch saying "Python (Version) \n it works!"

Try renaming the file from /home/sulphur1/basic/passenger_wsgi.py to /home/sulphur1/basic/passenger_wsgi (without the .py extension).
In your Passenger configuration (passenger_wsgi.py), ensure it refers to the correct module path (without the .py extension).
When running commands like python -m, make sure your virtual environment is activated for Python 3.x. If the bash python -m passenger_wsgi works, it could indicate your environment isn't consistently loading Python 3.x.
also ensure you're activating the Python 3.11 virtual environment before running the app; here sample:
source /home/sulphur1/virtualenv/basic/3.11/bin/activate

Then , run this too:
python -m passenger_wsgi

make sure a file permission is: 755

Thank's this problem solved. But python app showing folder structure (Index Of/) page even when I setup the passenger wsgi file as valid. Why is that happenning?
